# Do desk rejects happen after one and half months?

Tags: mathematics, paper-submission, rejection

I submitted a paper to a math journal and after one and half months (the status showed "under review") it was rejected without any report. Does this mean it was a desk rejection?

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for, but the brief answer is "yes".

Comment: If this is something that happened to you right now, also keep in mind that the preceding one and a half months include new years, christmas and thanksgiving, which might simply have delayed things compared to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not usual, but if the editor has trouble finding referees this can make them decide to desk reject.

I've been waiting almost two months for the editor to assign reviewers to one of my papers and I'm expecting a desk rejection at some point if they don't manage to find reviewers. The peer-review crisis is probably making this problem more common.

Comment: An apparent case of desk reject after failing to find referees can actually be found in [one of OP's earlier questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/196462/17254). One and a half months over the holidays seems too short a period to give up on though, so the comment about a quick expert's opinion seems more likely IMO.